# VBA Userform with DTPicker

Tags: vba, excel, datetimepicker, userform

Trying to make a Userform which has three inputs; Name (via txtbox), a combo-box-choice-menu and the DTPicker, which is giving me trouble.

I'm having trouble finding the error in this code, for some reason it keeps giving me a compiling error.

Screenshot added: [image: VBAProblem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTPicker requires MSCOMCT2.OCX which is no longer native to the OS since Windows 7. It would make more sense to re-think your design, as your end users will more than likely require this library too before it will work.

There is an alternative Date Picker control developed by Roy Cox that doesn't require this library [which can be found here](http://www.excel-it.com/excel_datepickers.html)

Comment: Thank you so much MacroMan. Consider this solved, i'll go look for a work-around.

Comment: You can download the MSCOMCT2.OCX file and manually register it to get this working if it's only yourself using it - but if you're planning on this being used on other machines I'd stay stay away from the MS Forms DT Picker.